# Type hint for a special argument

Tags: python, type-hinting

Consider the following function:

```
from datetime import date

def days_between(start_date: date, end_date: date) -> int:
    if start_date == "initial":
        start_date = date(2023, 9, 1)
    delta = end_date - start_date
    return delta.days
```

The type hint of start date is mostly fine, but it does not cover the case where `"initial"` is passed. This is the only string allowed, how would you express it?

The options I thought about are:

- `start_date: date | str` which seems a bit of an overkill
- `start_date: date | "initial"` maybe fine but I have not come across anything similar
- no change and simply add a description in the docstring

For completeness, I am more interested in how to convey the use of the function to a user compared to formal correctness for static type checking.

Comment: is "initial" the only allowed string?

Comment: yes it is, adding a clarification in the question

Comment: You mean `date | Literal["initial"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal)

```
from typing import Literal

def days_between(start_date: date | Literal['initial'], end_date: date) -> int:
    ...
```

This is included starting from python 3.8.

`Literal` can be used to indicate to type checkers that the annotated object has a value equivalent to one of the provided literals.